# How to display Emoji in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, emoji, android-jetpack-compose-text

Unable to display emojis properly using Jetpack Compose.

**Code**

```
    Text(
        text = data.emoji.character,
        textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
        fontSize = 28.sp,
    )
```

[image: Jetpack Compose text]

When using Compose `Text`, I am facing compatibility issues.
Tofu and multiple emojis appear as explained [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QVj2tQm8r58&ab_channel=AndroidDevelopers).

[image]

To fix this, I tried using `AppCompatTextView` in `AndroidView`.

**Code**

```
    AndroidView(
        factory = { context ->
            AppCompatTextView(context).apply {
                text = data.emoji.character
                textSize = 28F
                textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
            }
        },
    )
```

It displays the emojis without any compatibility issue, but the emojis are faded out.

[image]

Comment: Could you add a couple of emojis which doesn't work? I've took the first one which seems missing from your screenshot `""`, and it renders fine on my API 31 emulator.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov, You can see 9 Tofu in the first image. You can compare that with the second image to check which ones are not working.

Comment: BTW emoji compatibility issues might not be there in API 31 emulator. Try with some older versions 24 to 27.

Comment: you should check the `androidx.emoji2` library, https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/text-and-emoji/emoji2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to find [this issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/139326806), which is probably related to your `Text` problem. It's fixed in Compose **1.4.0**.

As to `AppCompatTextView`, it has default semi-transparent text color. Setting any color with alpha `1f` solves the problem:

```
AppCompatTextView(context).apply {
    setTextColor(Color.Black.toArgb())
    text = " hello"
    textSize = 28F
    textAlignment = View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER
}
```

Comment: does it support unicode instead of direct emoji?

Answer (score 2):

You can check the emoji in Compose page will all the relevant info https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/emoji

TL;DR modern emoji support is out of the box when using Compose 1.4 and above; some considerations apply when mixing in views.