# How to support emoji in Android using Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Just like the title, I found that emojis don't show up correctly in Jetpack Compose.

I'm going to make an offline app, so I'll use the **emoji2-bundle** or use the **NotoColorEmoji** font.

How to use the emoji2's component in Jetpack Compose (I tried using `AndroidView()`, but I don't know what arguments to pass in. Especially, the type of font's size in `Androidview()` is **Float** and not **TextUnit**(like **.sp**), I don't know how to convert it),

or get emojis in a **String** and use the **NotoColorEmoji** font in `buildAnnotatedString{ ... }`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display Emoji in Jetpack Compose?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70903309/how-to-display-emoji-in-jetpack-compose)